# How to pass System.PullRequest.TargetBranch to extends template and set then use the parameter to set variable conditionally

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to pass the PullRequest branch information to extends template. In my extends template I want to then use the parameter value to set a variable conditionally.

My main.yaml looks like
# main.yaml

```
extends:  
  template: /pipelines/template.yaml
  
  parameters:
    TargetBranch: $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)
```

My template.yaml is

```
#template.yaml

parameters:
  - name: TargetBranch
    type: string
    
variables:
  - name: param_targetBranch    
    ${{ if eq(parameters.TargetBranch, 'refs/heads/main') }}:    
      value: true
    ${{ else }}:
      value: false
  
stages:    
    - stage: teststage
      displayName: "test Stage"
      steps:
        - script: |    
            echo "Target Branch .." $(param_targetBranch)
```

I am raising the PullRequest for main branch but the `param_targetBranch` always returns `false`.

I understand there are some limitations around usage of System.PullRequest.TargetBranch, but just wondering if anyone has came up with a clever workaround that will solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` is a runtime variable. Template expansion happens [early in the run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline). During the expansion, the runtime variables don't exist. So `param_targetBranch` always returns false.

As a workaround, you can add a new stage before the stage that needs to consume `param_targetBranch` and define an output variable based on the value of `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch`. Refer to the sample below.

```
#template.yaml

stages:
- stage: one
  jobs:
  - job: set_var
    steps:
    - script: |
        if [ "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)" == "refs/heads/main" ]; then
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=targetbranch;isOutput=true]true"
        else
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=targetbranch;isOutput=true]false"
        fi
      name: setvarStep

- stage: two
  jobs:
  - job: consume_var
    variables:
      - name: param_targetBranch
        value: $[ stageDependencies.one.set_var.outputs['setvarStep.targetbranch'] ]
    steps:
    - script: echo "The value of param_targetBranch is " $(param_targetBranch)
```

In stage "one", job "set_var", task "setvarStep", if the value of `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` is `refs/heads/main`, then the value of output variable `targetbranch` is `true`, otherwise is `false`.

Define a new variable `param_targetBranch` in stage "two", job "consume_var". Set the value of it to `value: $[ stageDependencies.one.set_var.outputs['setvarStep.targetbranch'] ]`.

Then we can see the result as shown below:
[image]

[image]

See more info about output variable from [Share variables across pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#share-variables-across-pipelines).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to pass the value of param_targetBranch to nested template. I am struggling with that, seems like this variable is proccessed after Parameter values are set.

Will appreciate if you can point me to some work around for this.

Comment: Not sure about the structure of your pipeline, but if I add a template inside stage "two", this nested template can get the value of `param_targetBranch`. I just add "steps:
- script: echo "The value of param_targetBranch is " $(param_targetBranch)" in the nested template. If this is not what you expected. It is recommended that you create a new ticket for your new question.